# MalformedParameterizedTypeException When upgrading Spring Boot 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

When I tried to upgrade Spring Boot 2.1 to Spring boot 2.2 I have this StackTrace

```
2020-07-02 15:07:37.890  INFO 12116 --- [           main] f.i.e.EbadApplication                    : Starting EbadApplication on DWM1107403 with PID 12116 (C:\Developpement\ws\ebad\target\classes started by DTROUILLET in C:\Developpement\ws\ebad)
2020-07-02 15:07:37.894 DEBUG 12116 --- [           main] f.i.e.EbadApplication                    : Running with Spring Boot v2.3.0.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.6.RELEASE
2020-07-02 15:07:37.894  INFO 12116 --- [           main] f.i.e.EbadApplication                    : The following profiles are active: prod
2020-07-02 15:07:37.894 DEBUG 12116 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Loading source class fr.icdc.ebad.EbadApplication
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1 (file:/C:/Local/Maven2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.6/groovy-all-1.7.6.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1 (file:/C:/Local/Maven2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.6/groovy-all-1.7.6.jar) to method java.lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1 (file:/C:/Local/Maven2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.6/groovy-all-1.7.6.jar) to method java.lang.Object.registerNatives()
2020-07-02 15:07:38.123 DEBUG 12116 --- [           main] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: unknown
2020-07-02 15:07:38.138 ERROR 12116 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException: null
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:52) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:93) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.computeParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:279) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:330) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:391) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:118) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:74) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:58) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1047) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:462) ~[?:?]
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:205) ~[?:?]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:2940) ~[groovy-all-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2938) ~[groovy-all-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:2921) ~[groovy-all-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:166) ~[groovy-all-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:182) ~[groovy-all-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[groovy-all-1.7.6.jar:1.7.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.groovy.GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.<init>(GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java:150) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.<init>(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createBeanDefinitionLoader(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:681) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at fr.icdc.ebad.EbadApplication.main(EbadApplication.java:44) [classes/:?]

2020-07-02 15:07:38.152  WARN 12116 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@341a8659, started on Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:424) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:81) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:67) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:167) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at fr.icdc.ebad.EbadApplication.main(EbadApplication.java:44) [classes/:?]
```

So I upgrade all of my libs like spring, spring security oauth2, pf4j.
I don't knwow how to troubleshoot this.

I have the same StackTrace with JDK 8 and JDK 11

Link to my gist [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/dtrouillet/6c61f63bcdb9e78f7ae409206fd83ab4)

Comment: If you upgraded to 2.2 why is your logging about 2.3?

Comment: It's the exactly same stacktrace

Comment: Sorry your startup states Spring Boot 2.3.0 your question is about upgrading to 2.2.x. So your logging doesn't match your question. Next to that you started updating random libraries to who knows which version. Apparently ou are also using Groovy and a quite old one as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I clean my local maven repository folder and it works.
Is due to the org.codehaus.groovy concerned by Illegal reflective access.

Comment: Yep I delete the folder c:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-all\1.8.7\ and thats it  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your POM I see two dependencies not matching the version of Spring Boot 2 that is being used for other dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Your Parent POM is using

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

So please use the same for spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure

Comment: Can you please share your POM /build.gradle in the question

Comment: Unfortunaly I have the same result.